# Cannot import WebSocketApp form websocket in python

Tags: python, websocket

After installing websocket from pip, I am able to run the python interpreter and from there import WebSocketApp. But when I put same line, `from websoket import WebSocketApp`, in a file and try to run it, I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name WebSocketApp`.

What is happening here?

Comment: what is the version of websocket?

Comment: @GabrielAlberto Its 0.2.1

Answer (score 4):

Try to update this websocket to a latest version: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/0.37.0

I think the version 0.2.1 has not implemented WebsocketApp.

Answer (score 0):

try to install or upgrade websocket-client package

`pip install --upgrade websocket-client`